# If you can run short distance fast then can it be extended for longer distances without dropping off?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, speed, sprinting

If you can run one mile in 5:30 then are you guaranteed to be able to extend that pace to 5k, 10k, half marathon, or marathon distance? 
Ignoring time needed for exercising and building up for the distance.

---

After a year of running and learning more about it I can verify the two answers below are true. No you cant automatically extend the pace further unless you have the potential to run the shorter distance faster. In some cases I think training for longer distances help build you up for the shorter ones.

Comment: You appear to be asking several related questions, what is it exactly that you are trying to find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If your fastest pace for 1 mile is 5.30. Unfortunately the further you go the pace will drop off. There's various websites that will predict your race times based on other distances, ie I guess it works out your potential. Here's one http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/4/4_1/96.shtml

You can help reduce the drop of pace by interval training and a long run a week, but you can't stop it

Comment: I won't downvote, but it's a little unclear and way too broad to answer effectively. If he just goes out and runs a 5:30 mile, it's entirely possible that his top single mile could be much faster, and thus he could run a 5:30 for longer distances. But, he gives no details other than "ignoring time for buildup".

Comment: I agree that if he just runs a 5.30 mile than yes his top speed would be much quicker.  However, if I said I can run a 5.30 mile.  I think I'd be telling you my best time for that distance.  Therefore I would argue that it's the question that is unclear, as we both have a different interpretation of whether he just ran 5.30 or indeed, it was his top speed for the distance. As you say he gives no detail.  Maybe @Jason can expand on the question, making it clearer what he is asking, then we can both be more helpful

Comment: Agreed. I'm hoping he expands on what he's actually trying to find out.

Comment: I'm interested in the trend of pace related to distance, so this answer is great.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, it is possible, though not guaranteed. I did it for my 5KM and 10KM pace, not half and marathon. It comes down to training, and this is a lot of hard training.

Lets start off - a 5:30 mile is a strong pace, compare to your average runner, that is 3:25KMs or 17.56KM/h (10.9Miles/h).

I managed to build my pace over two years. When I started my 1 mile was close to yours, in November my 5 and 10KM pace was faster then my old 1 Mile pace. This was more an accident than a destination.

My journey started by going longer distances. By the time I did a few half marathons and marathons, a 5KM was very simple. I wanted to improve my half and full marathons pace. As such I used the 5KM and 10KM as chances to go hard. I would set the treadmill as high as possible and just go for as far as I could go. This translated to much faster road running. My half and marathon times dramatically improved but no-where near what my 5KM speed is.

Ultimately a 5:30 mile is a good pace to keep for a half marathon-even a 10KM. It would put you in the top 5% for big fun runs.

I say train really hard and eat clean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds like your taking the same approach to training that I am, but unfortunately running 5:30 in a mile is a mark I haven't hit yet; 6:18 mile & improving.